# Upload file in B4A

Tags: android

I'm new on the B4X platform and I am working on a B4A application in which I have to upload a file from my device to my local host I'm looking for a solution on the internet for one week but couldn't find any help,

Answer (score 0):

use the contentchooser library, for more details you can use this code

```
Sub Process_Globals
Private cc As ContentChooser
End Sub

Sub Globals
Private WebView1 As WebView
End Sub

Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean)
Activity.LoadLayout("1")
Dim client As JavaObject
client.InitializeNewInstance(Application.PackageName & ".main$MyChromeClient", 
Null)
Dim jo As JavaObject = WebView1
jo.RunMethod("setWebChromeClient", Array(client))
WebView1.LoadUrl("yourwebsite/index.php")
End Sub

Sub ShowFile_Chooser (FilePathCallback As Object, FileChooserParams As Object)
cc.Initialize("CC")
cc.Show("*/*", "Choose File")
Wait For CC_Result (Success As Boolean, Dir As String, FileName As String)
Dim jo As JavaObject = Me
If Success Then
    Log(FileName)
    File.Copy(Dir, FileName, Starter.Provider.SharedFolder, "TempFile")
    jo.RunMethod("SendResult", Array(Starter.Provider.GetFileUri("TempFile"), 
FilePathCallback))
Else
    jo.RunMethod("SendResult", Array(Null, FilePathCallback))
End If
End Sub
```